# Jquery UI Sortable Safari Glitch

Tags: jquery-ui, safari

I have a sortable element using jQuery ui. It works fine on all browsers except Safari 5.1

In Safari, sometimes some of the rows being sorted get out of the table. Specially the middle rows. Drag them up and down and they show outside to the left of the table.

It only happens when I set the axis:y.

Here is an example of my code http://jsfiddle.net/7zJnv/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd skip the axis option and use the containment option instead.

```
$("#planItem-listBody").sortable({
        containment: "parent"
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7zJnv/8/)**